inDesign Script Errors for Batch Exporting
I need to batch process exporting pages from an INDD document into different formats. here is what I have so far:
var pdfPreset1 = app.pdfExportPresets.item("[Smallest File Size]");
var pdfPreset2 = app.pdfExportPresets.item("[High Quality Print]");

// Export Page 1 as Smallest File Size PDF
var pdfFile1 = new File(app.activeDocument.fullName + "_page1.pdf");
var page1pdf = app.activeDocument.pages.item(0);
var pdfExportOptions1 = pdfPreset1;
page1pdf.exportFile(ExportFormat.pdfType, pdfFile1, false, pdfExportOptions1);

// Export Page 2 as High Quality Print PDF
var pdfFile2 = new File(app.activeDocument.fullName + "_page2.pdf");
var page2pdf = app.activeDocument.pages.item(1);
var pdfExportOptions2 = pdfPreset2;
page2pdf.exportFile(ExportFormat.pdfType, pdfFile2, false, pdfExportOptions2);

// Export Pages 3-10 as RGB JPG 72DPI
for (var i = 2; i < 11; i++) {
    var jpgOptions = new ExportOptionsSaveForWeb();
    jpgOptions.quality = 72;
    jpgOptions.colorSpace = ColorSpaceEnum.RGB;
    var jpgFile = new File(app.activeDocument.fullName + "_page" + i + ".jpg");
    app.activeDocument.pages.item(i).export(jpgFile, ExportFormat.jpg, jpgOptions);
}

// Export Page 11 as RGB PNG 72DPI
var pngOptions = new ExportOptionsPNG();
pngOptions.resolution = 72;
pngOptions.colorSpace = ColorSpaceEnum.RGB;
var pngFile = new File(app.activeDocument.fullName + "_page11.png");
app.activeDocument.pages.item(10).export(pngFile, ExportFormat.png, pngOptions);

// Export Pages 12-13 as RGB JPG 300DPI
for (var i = 11; i < 14; i++) {
    var jpgOptions = new ExportOptionsSaveForWeb();
    jpgOptions.quality = 300;
    jpgOptions.colorSpace = ColorSpaceEnum.RGB;
    var jpgFile = new File(app.activeDocument.fullName + "_page" + i + ".jpg");
    app.activeDocument.pages.item(i).export(jpgFile, ExportFormat.jpg, jpgOptions);
}

// Export Pages 14-17 as RGB JPG 72DPI
for (var i = 13; i < 18; i++) {
    var jpgOptions = new ExportOptionsSaveForWeb();
    jpgOptions.quality = 72;
    jpgOptions.colorSpace = ColorSpaceEnum.RGB;
    var jpgFile = new File(app.activeDocument.fullName + "_page" + i + ".jpg");
    app.activeDocument.pages.item(i).export(jpgFile, ExportFormat.jpg, jpgOptions);
}

// Export Page 18 as RGB JPG 300DPI
var jpgOptions = new ExportOptionsSaveForWeb();
jpgOptions.quality = 300;
jpgOptions.colorSpace = ColorSpaceEnum.RGB;
var jpgFile = new File(app.activeDocument.fullName + "_page18.jpg");
app.activeDocument.pages.item(17).export(jpgFile, ExportFormat.jpg, jpgOptions);

// Export Pages 19-22 as RGB JPG 72DPI
for (var i = 18; i < app.activeDocument.pages.length; i++) {
    var jpgOptions = new ExportOptionsSaveForWeb();
    jpgOptions.quality = 72;
    jpgOptions.colorSpace = ColorSpaceEnum.RGB;
    var jpgFile = new File(app.activeDocument.fullName + "_page" + i + ".jpg");
    app.activeDocument.pages.item(i).export(jpgFile, ExportFormat.jpg, jpgOptions);
}

This currently generating the following error:
Error number: 24
Error String: page1.pdf.exportFile is not a function
Engine: main
File: /User/claire/Library/Preferences/Adobe InDesign/Version 19.0/en_GB/Scripts/Scripts Panel/Campaign Export.js
Line: 8
Souce: page1.pdf.exportFile(ExportFormat.pdfType, pdfFile1, false, pdfExportOptions1);
The end result is to export the files as so:
Page 1 Smallest File Size PDF 72 DPI and a High Quality Print CKYK PDF 300DPI
Page 2 Smallest File Size PDF 72 DPI and a High Quality Print CKYK PDF 300DPI
Page 3-10 RBG JPG 72DPI
Page 11 RGB PNG 72DPI
Pages 12-13 RGB JPG 300DPI
Pages 14-17 RGB 72DPI JPG
Page 18 RBG JPG 300DPI
Pages 19-22 RGB JPG 72DPI
Any help gratefully received please :)

Try assigning a string of the desired file path & name to pdfFile1 and using page1pdf.exportFile(ExportFormat.pdfType, File(pdfFile1), false, pdfExportOptions1);

The object Page has no method exportFile(). Document has. You have to use app.activeDocument.exportFile(...), and add to the presets the number of page. Something like: app.pdfExportPreferences.pageRange = '1'
